# ignorar un archivo xml utilizando python?

Tags: python, xml

Necesito ayuda, el codigo que tengo en python lee los archivos xml dentro de una carpeta predeterminada, una vez encontrados dichos archivos los lee y saca los datos requeridos dentro del mismo, el detalle es que encontre varios xml que contienen errores y ahi es cuando mi programa se detiene, hay una manera de ignorar esos archivos y mandarlos a otra carpeta? Gracias.

```
root = 'C:/Users/.../'

fnames = [ arch.name for arch in os.scandir( root ) if(arch.is_file() ) ]

infiles = [open( root + fname, "r", encoding = "utf-8").read()for fname in 
fnames]

columnas = []
for contents in infiles:
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
Emisores = soup.find('cfdi:Emisor')
Receptor = soup.find('cfdi:Receptor')
Comprobante = soup.find('cfdi:Comproante')
Concepto = soup.find('cfdi:Concepto')
Impuestos = soup.find('cfdi:Traslado')
Timbres = soup.find('tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital')
EmisorNombre = Emisores.get('Nombre')
EmisorRfc = Emisores.get('Rfc')
ReceptorNombre = Receptor.get('Nombre')
ReceptorRfc = Receptor.get('Rfc')
TipoComprobante = Comprobante.get('TipoDeComprobante')
Fecha = Comprobante.get('Fecha')
LugarExpedicion = Comprobante.get('LugarExpedicion')
Serie = Comprobante.get('Serie')    #No todas tienen serie, hacer try 
Folio = Comprobante.get('Folio')
Moneda = Comprobante.get('Moneda')
SubTotal = Comprobante.get('SubTotal')
Descuento = Concepto.get('Descuento')     #No todos tienen descuento, hacer un try



#Iva = Impuestos.get('Importe')

#ImpRetenidos = Impuestos.get('TotalImpuestosRetenidos')    #No todos tienen impuestos retenidos, hacer un try
Total = Comprobante.get('Total')
MetodoPago = Comprobante.get('MetodoPago')
FormaPago = Comprobante.get('FormaPago')
UsoCFDI = Receptor.get('UsoCFDI')
Version = Comprobante.get('Version')
UUID = Timbres.get('UUID')
NoCertificado = Comprobante.get('NoCertificado')

columnas.append([EmisorNombre, EmisorRfc,ReceptorNombre, ReceptorRfc, TipoComprobante, Fecha, LugarExpedicion, Serie, Folio, Moneda, SubTotal, Descuento,
                 Total, MetodoPago, FormaPago, UsoCFDI, Version, UUID, NoCertificado])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más fácil es utilizar `Try`

Así podría quedar tu codigo:

```
root = 'C:/Users/.../'

fnames = [ arch.name for arch in os.scandir( root ) if(arch.is_file() ) ]

infiles = [open( root + fname, "r", encoding = "utf-8").read()for fname in 
fnames]

columnas = []

for contents in infiles:
    try: 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
        Emisores = soup.find('cfdi:Emisor')
        Receptor = soup.find('cfdi:Receptor')
        Comprobante = soup.find('cfdi:Comproante')
        Concepto = soup.find('cfdi:Concepto')
        Impuestos = soup.find('cfdi:Traslado')
        Timbres = soup.find('tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital')
        EmisorNombre = Emisores.get('Nombre')
        EmisorRfc = Emisores.get('Rfc')
        ReceptorNombre = Receptor.get('Nombre')
        ReceptorRfc = Receptor.get('Rfc')
        TipoComprobante = Comprobante.get('TipoDeComprobante')
        Fecha = Comprobante.get('Fecha')
        LugarExpedicion = Comprobante.get('LugarExpedicion')
        Serie = Comprobante.get('Serie')    #No todas tienen serie, hacer try 
        Folio = Comprobante.get('Folio')
        Moneda = Comprobante.get('Moneda')
        SubTotal = Comprobante.get('SubTotal')
        Descuento = Concepto.get('Descuento')     #No todos tienen descuento, hacer un try

        #Iva = Impuestos.get('Importe')

        #ImpRetenidos = Impuestos.get('TotalImpuestosRetenidos')    #No todos tienen impuestos retenidos, hacer un try
        Total = Comprobante.get('Total')
        MetodoPago = Comprobante.get('MetodoPago')
        FormaPago = Comprobante.get('FormaPago')
        UsoCFDI = Receptor.get('UsoCFDI')
        Version = Comprobante.get('Version')
        UUID = Timbres.get('UUID')
        NoCertificado = Comprobante.get('NoCertificado')

        columnas.append([EmisorNombre, EmisorRfc,ReceptorNombre, ReceptorRfc, TipoComprobante, Fecha, LugarExpedicion, Serie, Folio, Moneda, SubTotal, Descuento,
                         Total, MetodoPago, FormaPago, UsoCFDI, Version, UUID, NoCertificado])

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Entonces podría ser:
try:
infiles = [open( root + fname, "r", encoding = "utf-8").read()for fname in 
fnames]
except: 
?

Comment: mi recomendación es que utilices el try justo cuando inicie el `for`de esa manera si encuentra un error al obtener alguna de tus variables va a iniciar el código de error, ahí puedes poner  `pass` y entonces se habrá saltado el archivo defectuoso. En un momento actualizo mi respuesta y pongo como lo propongo

Comment: Perfecto muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Y en caso de querer ignorar un archivo con una codificacion diferente? O cambiar la codificacion? Ya que cuando se tiene un archivo con una codificacion diferente igual se detiene...

Comment: No se la verdad si entendí bien, la cuestión, pero podrías añadir un nuevo `try` al momento de generar la lista de `infiles` ya que ahí está tu encoding